# Why doesn't my video backgorund play in Android (VideoView)?

Tags: java, android, xml, video, android-videoview

I implemented a video background in the main activity of my Android app. I tried debugging it on my phone and in the emulator, but I always get the "can't play video" error. It's an mp4 file. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_video_view_demo );

    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById( R.id.introView );
    Uri uri = Uri.parse( "android.resource"+  getPackageName() + "/" +
            R.raw.bgvideo );
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController( this );
    mediaController.setAnchorView( videoView );
    videoView.setMediaController( mediaController );
    videoView.setVideoURI( uri );
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
```

and here is the specific error I notice in the log:

```
yer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

10-05 16:40:33.608 28461-28461/com.example.ecohapp E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0

Not very postitive of what isn't working. I have all the required imports.

Comment: If you can play other MP4 with your shown code, then problem is with your video file.. Download and test this [**MP4** file](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() + "/" +
            R.raw.bgvideo );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other posted Answer (about `uri` etc) might help you...

but if the video is also not playable by Android's own Video Gallery app then consider:

Use [**MediaInfo**](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) tool (download via web). Check your video's **profile** setting. It could be `Baseline`, `Main` or `High`. Most mobile devices will play `baseline` (even older models).

If it's not `baseline` then use a video tool to convert (choose `baseline` in your output settings) and re-test on your device.